# Continuous Monotonic Functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a non-decreasing function. Can we find a sequence of continuous non-decreasing functions $f_{n}:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ such that $ \{ f_{n} \} $
converge  to $f$ in $L^{1}([a,b])$?

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards,
Maury Barbato

Comment: For a related question see http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7370918.

Comment: There was a comment here, "Convolution with a smooth, compactly supported and non-negative approximate identity should give you what you want.", deleted by its author shortly after posting, that answers your question. Just extend the monotonic function to a larger interval before convolving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is considering convolution product of $f$ with some suitable [approximation to the identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function).

Indeed, let's assume $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is non-decreasing locally integrable (starting from a function on $[a,b]$ we can extend it to a non-decreasing locally integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $f(x) = \inf f([a,b])$ for $x \le a$ and $f(x) = \sup f([a,b])$ for $x \ge b$). Pick any  non-negative compactly supported smooth function $g$. Then the convolution product $f*g$ defined as

$$(f*g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x-t) g(t) \, dt$$

is also non-decreasing and smooth. Now for simplicity assume that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g = 1$, and denote $g_n(x) = n g(nx)$ (such a sequence $(g_n)_{n \ge 0}$ is called an approximation to the identity) and $f_n = f*g_n$. Then $f_n$ are smooth non-increasing functions such that $f_n \to f$.

Comment: Thank you very much Joen for having kindly answered my question. I would have never thought about convolutions!